# What technologies to use for web + mobile app

Tags: web, mobile

Me and my teammates were assigned a school project where we are supposed to create a mobile application and a web page that function together. The problem we have is we are very confused about which technologies to focus on.

The application is supposed to enable users to pay for paid parking zones. The user should be able to see where are the areas in which you have to pay for parking and how much (we imagined colored zones on a map). The website should work similar - map with parking zones, with account management, but no ability to pay for parking.

Someone pointed us to try ionic 2 for mobile app (we tought about android SDK), and we tought about using spring framework for doing backend stuff. But when we searched for spring tutorials we saw that it seemed to do both backend and frontend, there are 5 of us so we tought it would be unproductive if we all learn the same thing.

I ask for some help about which direction should we take, which technologies can work together (some common technologies overview would be much appreciated too).

Comment: Pretty much any mobile technology stack and any web technology stack will work.  You can use whichever appeals to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello i think the best mobile technology is for web development is IONIC combined with Ng-cordova its the best and the fastest way for someone who knows web programming. and also there is another framework called Phone Gap